# Force TFS buildserver to compile csproj files in a specific order

Tags: c#, .net, build

after applying the suggested changes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24822723/937093) my buildserver is unable to build the affected solutions.

The problem is that the .NET 4.0 and the .NET 4.5 projects are compiled after eachother.

As an example let's assume that I've 4 projects: `a.csproj`, `b.csproj`, `c.csproj`. All projects have a .NET 4.0 and a .NET 4.5 version, meaning that I've `a.csproj`, `a_40.csproj`, `b.csproj`, `b_40.csproj`, `c.csproj` and `c_40.csproj`. Some of those projects depend on another project inside the solution. So for example `b*.csproj` depends on `a*.csproj`. Also the output library of `a.csproj` and `a_40.csproj` have the same name: `a.dll`.

Now instead of going the sane way and compiling all 4.0 assemblies and then all 4.5 assemblies, TFS, as usual, chooses the insane way and builds everything in a completely randomized order while using the same output folder for all projects. Which of course fails.

I guess there are at least two solutions to that problem:

1. Instead of throwing everything in the same build folder, use one folder for each project or at least one per .NET version. (as Visual Studio does)
2. Force the TFS to build the projects in a specific sequence (all .NET 4.0 assemblies first for example).

The problem: I've no idea how to do that.

My question: Can someone show me how to make either of my two suggested solutions work *or* show me another solution to this problem?

Comment: The insane thing is having multiple versions of projects. Try changing your build definition to use separate output folders per solution?

Comment: uh I'm doing that already? @JohnSaunders

Comment: One output folder per solution? Normally there would be one output for the entire build.

Comment: @JohnSaunders there is a setting in the TFS's build manager where you can change that. Sadly it's only for solutions, not for the csproj files.

Comment: That's why I used the term "solution" in my comment. If each solution is all one version, and if you use one folder per solution, maybe that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027551/937093

By adding two build configurations to all affected solutions (one for building the .NET 4 projects and one for building the .NET 4.5 projects) and creating two builddefinitions in TFS I got the thing working the way I wanted it.

Comment: You can also add two configurations to one Build Definition, each will output to its own output folder. Though the dropdowns show only standard configurations, you can enter manual configs here as well. Each configuration should be dropped in it's own subfolder. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#configs

Answer (score -1):

I don't use TFS as build machine (I prefer Jenkins or other CI tool), but all servers allows you to create your own MSBuild Script to do your builds. A .csproj IS a MSBuild script.

If you create your own script you can setup your preferred order. Anyway, using .sln usually solves the dependencies correctly.

If you want to dig deeper in MSBuild, take a look at the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx

A sample script would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
<PropertyGroup>
    <TextToSay>This is a property</TextToSay>   
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Binaries Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MSBuildTests\**\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>

<UsingTask TaskName="GenerateDumbFiles" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MSBuildTests\MSBuildTests.Tasks\bin\Debug\MSBuildTests.Tasks.dll" />

<Target Name="SaySomething">
    <Message Text="$(TextToSay)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Build">
    <Delete Files="@(Binaries)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MSBuildTests\MSBuildTests.sln" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\dumbfiles" />
    <GenerateDumbFiles Directory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\dumbfiles" Prefix="DumbFile" Count="100" />
</Target>

<Target Name="TransformLog">
    <XslTransformation XmlInputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\msbuild-output.xml" XslInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\msbuild.xsl" OutputPaths="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\log.html" />
</Target>
```

The MSBuild task is used to compile stuff in .NET.

Comment: so your suggestion would be to throw the .sln aside, link all .csproj files directly into the TFS build service and supply the arguments for the MSBuild command manually?

Comment: While other build tools are great too, they're not *the* solution.